Liquibase Rollback functionality stopped working after applying seed data
We are doing a POC on the tool Liquibase to integrate our database changes into a CI/CD pipeline. After applying some seed data with the loadData command (https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/load-data.html), we removed the changelog from the root-changelog.yaml and also removed the entry in the DATABASECHANGELOG table since rolling back loadData isn't supported. We attempted to rollback the previous change (creating a different table) by both the changelog count and tag, but neither work now. I know it worked before we did the loadData. Does anyone know why this isn't working as expected? If I removed it from the DATABASECHANGELOG table and the changelog, I wouldn't expect Liquibase to get stuck on the seed data since it's rolling back a single table creation that both wasn't touched with the seed data and is the last changelog

Applied a changelog to create table
databaseChangeLog:
- changeSet:
    id: 1718741122446-1
    author: Josh Lester <jlester@velocityrisk.com>
    changes:
    - createTable:
        columns:
        - column:
            autoIncrement: true
            computed: false
            constraints:
              nullable: false
            name: Id
            type: int
        - column:
            computed: false
            constraints:
              nullable: false
            name: Html
            type: nvarchar(MAX)
        - column:
            computed: false
            constraints:
              nullable: false
            name: StartDateTimeUtc
            type: datetime
        - column:
            computed: false
            name: EndDateTimeUtc
            type: datetime
        tableName: Announcement



Applied seed data changelog
databaseChangeLog:
- changeSet:
    id: 1718982752065-2
    author: liquibase (generated)
    changes:
    - loadData:
        columns:
        - column:
            header: Id
            name: Id
            type: NUMERIC
        - column:
            header: Category
            name: Category
            type: NUMERIC
        - column:
            header: Weight
            name: Weight
            type: NUMERIC
        - column:
            header: BusinessUnit
            name: BusinessUnit
            type: STRING
        commentLineStartsWith: '#'
        encoding: UTF-8
        file: appetitecategoryweight.csv
        quotchar: '"'
        separator: ','
        tableName: AppetiteCategoryWeight

"Category","Weight","BusinessUnit"
"0","0.300","XXX"
"1","0.300","XXX"
"2","0.250","XXX"
"3","0.150","XXX"
"0","0.200","XXX"
"1","0.250","XXX"
"2","0.350","XXX"
"3","0.200","XXX"



Removed seed data changelog and from DATABASECHANGELOG table

Attempted to rollback changelog to create table


Expected: liquibase would rollback the table creation
What happened: liquibase changed nothing
